Footnotes floating in the middle of the paper
I need to make a paper for school with latex. We have precise margins that we need to follow.
I want the space between the line of the footnote/footcites to be 2pc or further away from the bottom of my text. The bottom of the footnotes should be exactly 2cm away from the end of the page. I used
\setlength{\skip\footins}{2pc}

to set the distance between the bottom of the text and the line of the footnotes and set the margins with
\geometry{a4paper, left=2.5 cm, right=2.5 cm, top=2.5 cm, bottom=2 cm, heightrounded=true}

The spacing is working correctly but now the footnotes float way above 2cm away from the bottom of the page. 

Welcome to TeX.SE.

Add [showframe] to geometry to see the text area boundaries.

I suggest you add the instruction
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}

to the preamble of your document.
Incidentally, if your document loads both setspace and footmisc, then setspace must be loaded before footmisc. This constraint is mentioned on page 9 of the user guide of the footmisc packaage.

Perfect this worked for me. Thanks a lot :)
